# Approximation to the characteristic function

Tags: probability-distributions, characteristic-functions, moment-generating-functions

The characteristic function is computed as follows
$$
\varphi (t) = \left\langle e^{i t X} \right\rangle
$$

When the right-hand side is expanded, we get
$$
\varphi (t) = 1 + i t \left\langle X \right\rangle - \frac{t^2}{2} \left\langle X^2 \right\rangle - \frac{i t^3}{3!} \left\langle X^3 \right\rangle + \cdots
$$

Let's say we don't really know the distribution for $X$, or its full characteristic function, we only know $\left\langle X \right\rangle$. In that case, I think, a good approximation to $\varphi$ would be (to my best knowledge)
$$
\varphi (t) = \left\langle e^{i t X} \right\rangle \approx e^{i t \left\langle X \right\rangle}
$$
(this yields a $\delta$-function as a distribution for $X$, which makes sense, since we only provided the mean value)

What if I know both $\left\langle X \right\rangle$ and $\left\langle X^2 \right\rangle$? Can I somehow write down something very similar keeping in mind that I only know these two moments? In this case it would probably be a Gaussian, since it already contains both $\left\langle X \right\rangle$ and $\left\langle X^2 \right\rangle$ as its parameters. What if I know first $n$ moments, is it then possible to write down a characteristic function or distribution itself that would yield these moments? What about distributions of several variables and knowing all expectation values of various combinations up to some order $n$? Thank you.

Comment: Well if $X = N(0,1)$ is a standard normal, then $\langle e^{X} \rangle = e^{1/2} \neq e^{\langle X \rangle} = 1$, so I don't think this is a "good" approximation, unless I am interpreting $\langle \cdot \rangle$ incorrectly as the mean.

Comment: Okay, I guess my question is then how do I cook up a distribution whose first n moments are going to be equal to what I know they should be?

Comment: @user16320 That revised question [doesn't sound like it really has anything to do with characteristic functions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). You may be interested in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Distributions_with_measured_constants).